# Add Disclaimer Screen

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to add a `disclaimerViewController` to my application as the initial `viewController`, which, if accepted will lead the user tot he `entryViewController`, and if not, will not allow the user to use the application. However, I want to to be that if the user accepts the disclaimer, any time after he opens the application he won't be presented with the  `disclaimerViewControleler` but with the `entryViewController`.

I know that it has something do to with editing the `AppDelegate.swift` file, but am unsure of were to start.

Comment: This has been asked MANY times before. Please search before asking. Here's an example solution: https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this was marked as a duplicate? Both your answer and your iOS project do not support disclaimers.

Comment: Both poodles and spaniels are dogs. You need to make a dog; it's merely a contingent fact what breed it is. As I said, the problem of one-time presentation of a view controller (or until the user satisfies some requirement) is heavily dealt with here already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save user choice in UserDefaults

The code below is using Swift 3

If you don't want to load entryViewController then In the AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //retrieve values from UserDefaults
        //for the first time it will be false, because it was not set earlier
        let isAccepted = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isAccepted")

        if isAccepted == false {
           //present your disclaimer here
        }else{
           //show entryViewController
        }

        return true
}
```

Or you can load entryViewController and present disclaimer instantly, then in your entryViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   //retrieve values from UserDefaults
   //for the first time it will be false, because it was not set earlier
   let isAccepted = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isAccepted")

   if isAccepted == false {
      //present your disclaimer here      
   }
}
```

In the DisclaimerVC:

```
@IBAction func accept(_ sender: UIButton){
    //it can be another action in your controller
    //but anyway, you should save user choice after that
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isAccepted")

    //add code here to dismiss disclaimer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about doing this is by setting your `disclaimerViewController` to the initial view controller in your storyboard file.

In the swift file check to see if the user has previously accepted the disclaimer in the `viewDidLoad` method, if they haven't, allow the code to function normally and display the screen, if they have push the user on to your `entryViewController`

If you want to set your initial view controller in the AppDelgate and not in the storyboard, here is a useful link: [set initial viewcontroller in appdelegate - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753925/set-initial-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate-swift)

To transition to a new viewcontroller in swift, here is a useful link:  [Switching view controllers in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045161/switching-view-controllers-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The smoothest way to implement this is to switch the views programmatically.

Make sure to set the restoration ids for your ViewControllers in the StoryBoard.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var mainViewController: ViewController?
    var acceptViewController: AcceptViewController?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        mainViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView") as? ViewController
        acceptViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AcceptView") as? AcceptViewController
        if mainViewController == nil {
            print("mainViewController is nil")
        }
        if acceptViewController == nil {
            print("acceptViewController is nil")
        }

        let isAccepted = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isAccepted")

        if isAccepted == false {
            switchToAcceptViewController()
        } else {
            switchToMainViewController()
        }
        return true
    }

    func switchToMainViewController() {
        //mainViewController?.selectedIndex = 0 // only needed if the main view controller is a tab view
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    func switchToAcceptViewController() {
        //mainViewController?.selectedIndex = 0 // only needed if the main view controller is a tab view
        self.window?.rootViewController = acceptViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

AcceptViewController

```
class AcceptViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func acceptAction(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isAccepted")
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.switchToMainViewController()
    }

}
```

You can get the full project here: https://github.com/ryantxr/legendary-fiesta